# How to set up CORS properly on IIS?

Tags: jquery, cordova, iis, asp.net-web-api, cors

I've recently started working on an a PhoneGap mobile application that will authenticate and work with ASP.NET WebApi web services.  One of my issues early on was to enable CORS in IIS using a setting in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This setting in part of my .NET WebAPI application.  Looking at the above, it appears that it opens up Access control for absolutely everyone, but I'm not sure what else could possibly go into the value portion of the header.  The mobile apps (HTML, JavaScript, etc) are all on mobile devices, making jQuery calls to the API on the server.

My API / HTML seem to work as expected with the above setting in place.  If I remove it, I get CORS errors.  Is the above normal, or should it something more specific?

Comment: Hi LTMOD my answer is okay for you or not , please let me know if it isn't okay for you ,thanks

Comment: Hi Willie, sorry, no.  My question is more about whether the asterisk in the value should be allowed or if it should be something more specific.  I just don't see the point of CORS in the first place, if you're simply going to allow everyone to access the resource.

Comment: Yes , you are right , but in my case ,there is usually using Authentication and Authorization to protect your data , hopefully this message can assist you , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to put the code WebApiConfig as like below code

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
        }
}
```

**by the way  you have to download "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" for EnableCors  by Nuget**

Answer (score 0):

This link describes CORS and how that works with WebAPI in detail.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors